# Symfony Set value of a form field in doSave

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I need to override my form like this:

```
  protected function doSave($con = null)
  {
    $filename= Helper::generateFilename($this->getValue('name')).'jpg';
    imagejpeg(Helper::createImage($this->getValues()), sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/poster/'.$filename );
    /* Here I need to set value of *fielname* field of the form equal to 
     $filename  */
    parent::doSave($con);
  }
```

`Helper.class.php` is located in `/lib/`so it acts like a helper class.

`generateFilename` actually gives a randomized string. since there is no function like `setValue` in a form, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use, say you have used `filename` as field in your schema to store the image filename, `$this->object->setFilename($filename);` before `parent::doSave($con);`

Answer (score 1):

I tried macgyver's approach but didn't work for me. Not sure if I did anything wrong.
Syfmony version is 1.4 with Doctrine.

I had to override the updateObject() function inside the form class.
In my case its inside TimesheetForm.class.php. I had to change the status of the timesheet based on user action.

Following is the piece of code that that I tried. It did update the object before saving. Which was seen effected in the db.

```
    public function updateObject($values = null)
    {
        $object = parent::updateObject($values);
        $object->setStatus("Submitted");

        return $object;
    }
```

I didn't impelement/override the doSave() function. I'm using symfony 1.4.
Hope the above helps.